# How to remove key of JSON and return entire thing as Content?

Tags: apache-nifi

My attribute employee has below JSON value:

```
{"testQuery": {"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} }}
```

I want to send the `{"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} }` to a customizedProcessor as flowFile content not as attribute, need to perform the following,

1. Remove the testQuery key from the JSON value of attribute employee,
2. Convert the value of testQuery to flowFile content and return.

Comment: Means that, {"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} } should be returned as FlowFile content finally.

Comment: What happens if you define a new attribute with `${employee.testQuery}`? Is this attribute are same with `{"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} }`? Then, use ReplaceText

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have `employee` attribute in the flow file with value:

```
{"testQuery": {"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} }}
```

Flow to get `{"$set": {"name":"Harsh"} }` as a flow file content:

```
1. ReplaceText       - to store attribute into content
   Replacement Value = ${employee}

2. EvaluateJsonPath  - to extract required json value and put into content
   Destination       = flowfile-content
   value             = $.testQuery
```